# ListView hangs when i click on an Item

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a `selectWord()` function that populates two strings and an `ArrayList`, then it puts them(strings) into `ListView` and `TextView`.

What I want to do is when someone clicks on the `listItem`, the strings and `ArrayList` should change their values and put new values in `TextView` and `ListView`.

I created a function that selects words from text file and then shows that data into views, in `ClickListener`; what I did is call to the same function again so that it selects data from text file and put it into the views. (*a quiz type app, select an option and then next question*)

I wrote similar code couple of days ago that work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();    //words list
    private ArrayList<String> defns = new ArrayList<>();    //deffinitions
    private String word;
    private String correct;
    public ArrayList<String> randOptions = new ArrayList<>();
    private Random randy = new Random();
    private TextView wordView;
    private ListView optionView;

    public void readFile() { //works fine
        //populate the ArrayLists
        String word, defn;
        Scanner file = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(raw.dictionary1));

        while(file.hasNextLine()) {
              String line = file.nextLine();
              String[] lineArray = line.split(" ");
              if (lineArray.length >= 2) {
                  word = lineArray[0];
                  defn = lineArray[1];
                  words.add(word);
                  defns.add(defn);
              }
          }
    }

    public void selectWord() {

        readFile(); //read file
        //get some data
        int rand = randy.nextInt(words.size());
        this.word = words.get(rand);
        this.correct = defns.get(rand);

        //make 4 diff options
        randOptions.add(correct);

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            rand = randy.nextInt(defns.size());
            if(randOptions.contains(defns.get(rand)))
                    i--;
            else
                randOptions.add(defns.get(rand));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(randOptions);

        //add the data to views
        wordView.setText(this.word);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, randOptions);
        optionView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(layout.activity_main);

        wordView = findViewById(id.currentWord);
        optionView = findViewById(id.options);

        selectWord();

        optionView.setOnItemClickListener(
              new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                       String selected = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                       if (correct.equals(selected)) {
                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       } else {
                              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                       selectWord(); //so that it changes the vlaues in views but when I add that 
                       //line my hangs there soon as I click on the list item
               }
           }
       );    
}
```

Comment: what should I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optionView.setOnItemClickListener(...)` uses `AdapterView`. So when you call `selectWord();` from *inside* this `ClickListener` it hangs... **Why?**: Simply because you are re-creating the `ArrayAdapter<String>` and setting it again in the `ListView`.

Instead of asking it to kill itself (i.e. recreate itself from ground), you can ask the `ArrayAdapter` to change its data so the `ListView` will still use the same `ArrayAdapter`. In this case, you should notify the changes, something like this:

1. First remove `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ..` and `optionView.setAdapter` from `selectWord()` method.
2. Create *global* `ArrayAdapter` and set it in the `ListView` outside the `selectWord()` method.
3. Then every time you want to change the options ..etc call `selectWord()`.
4. Then clear the `ArrayAdapter` and repopulate it again.
5. Finally notify changes.

---

```
// create this method to update the options (re-populate the ArrayAdapter)
// of course ArrayAdapter and randOptions should be GLOBAL
public void updateOptions() {
    adapter.clear(); 
    if (randOptions != null){
       for (String option : randOptions) {
           adapter.insert(option,adapter.getCount());
        }
    }     
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

```
// first declare the ArrayAdapter globally as a field
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// inside onCreate() method, initialize the ArrayAdapter (i.e. outside the `selectWord()` method) 
// using this constructor: ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

// after that, set the adapter (it's empty by now)
optionView.setAdapter(adapter);

// fill the Random Options Array
selectWord();
// call update options
updateOptions();

// and use it inside the CLickListener like this
optionView.setOnItemClickListener(
          new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // whatever ...
                selectWord(); //so that it changes the options in the array
                updateOptions(); // update options in the same ArrayAdapter
})});
```